# Plotting a GLM with two variables

Tags: plot, glm

I fitted a GLM and it takes into account two different variables.

I know how to plot a multivariate LM, by plotting one of the variables while taking into account the influence of the other (the second takes its average value), by using:

```
plot(var.of.interest ~ var1, data=dataset)
xs=seq(0,20,by=0.5)
pred=predict(myLm,newdata=data.frame(var1=xs,var2=mean(dataset$var2)))
lines(xs,pred)
```

in which we make the predictions of var.of.interest based on var1 conditional on the mean value of var2

once I try to use a GLM and predict.glm for this it still returns a linear regression instead of the GLM I created

```
glmDV = glm((RA_Ungulate+0.0001) ~ Veg_Understory+Distance ,data=data,family=Gamma(link="log"))

plot(RA_Ungulate~Distance,data=data)
xs=seq(0,23,by=1)
predAD=predict.glm(glmD,newdata=data.frame(Distance=xs),type="response")

# the code below doesnt work as intended because the predict.glm function returns a linear fit instead of the actual GLM...

pred=predict.glm(glmDV,newdata=data.frame(Distance=xs,Veg_Understory=data$Veg_Understory))
lines(xs,pred,col="orange")
```